# Wordpress - render one template for more than one url

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have created a wordpress template that loads for this page - example.com/products
The template name is page-products.php and it is located inside my theme folder.
It works only for http://example.com/products, is there any way I can make it work for templates like http://example.com/products/clothing, so when a user visits this url the page will be rendered from the products template?

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<!-- 
My Custom Products page
-->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: I will suggest to create custom taxonomy with name products and then create category in your custom taxonomy like clothing and etc. You will detail idea from here https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom page template to accomplish this. The file would be named something like `template-clothing.php`. Additionally, you could put this file in a sub-folder called `page-templates` if you have several page templates (this removes cluster from the root directory).
The header for your template could look like this:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Clothing
*/    
?>
```

Once this file has been created, the template can be selected under `Page Attributes` in the page editor, and the page will subsequently be displayed with this appearance.